Route Work Action - Clear agents Omni backlog
We are currently using the Omniflow to Route work to Agents, In some usecase we route the work to the dedicated agents using a high priority routing Config even when they are not Logged in Omni/ Doesnot have the Capacity. When they are available in omni with the Capacity these work items will be pushed in to their Omni Channel. We are experiencing an issue is that if the dedicated agents are out of office and those pushed work items gets manually assigned to another agent, gets closed. The closed case is still showing up in the dedicated agents Omni when he logs in next. How we can remove the PSR assigned to dedicated agents when the Cases are closed.
